# Handling cancel of the location services alert

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I do have a situation where I need to get current location of iPhone 5 running iOS8. When the location services is off, the default location service alert open up. This alert has 'Cancel' and 'Settings' button. Please find below the screenshot of the alert.
[image]

I need to handle the situation when user pressed cancel on the alert. I can handle it when I override the alert. But that alert isn't working for me, as settings of that custom alert takes me to the app level location settings and not device level location settings.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate for your CLLocationManager and implement the delegate's method 
`- locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`

This method is called whenever the application’s ability to use location services changes. Changes can occur because the user allowed or denied the use of location services for your application or for the system as a whole.

If the authorization status is already known when you call the requestWhenInUseAuthorization or requestAlwaysAuthorization method, the location manager does not report the current authorization status to this method. The location manager only reports changes to the authorization status. For example, it calls this method when the status changes from kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined to kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse.

[Link to Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. But we have surpassed the alert which you are mentioning. We are planning to act on cancel button of the alert which comes when location services are off and we try to access the location.

Comment: I don't think you can catch the cancel button tap event as it is an automatic system alert. All you can do is handle the delegate method. Normally this system alert shows when you first instantiate a CLLocationManager with an authorization status value of `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`. If user press cancel I think you can't get the event.